# How to remove underline from text hyperlink?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseover, underline

I got a problem in my css file, I used this following code:

```
text-decoration: none;
```

But still it doesnt have effect on text, for some reason I had to use java script for href link behind text. But I think so because of this issue text decoration doesn't has effect on the text. 
even I can't use different color on text like hover and mouse over color.

Here is code:

```
 $(function() 
{
$('.maincaptionsmall').wrapInner('<a href="http://google.com"></a>');
});
```

and here is html code:

```
<span class="maincaptionsmall">Home</span>
```

For your information I used text decoration none even inline of href code, but it doesn't has effect.

I'm gonna remove underline from Home text and use different color for mouse over something like this:

```
:hover { color: yellow; }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS for <A> tag

```
a {text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {color: yellow;}
```

CSS for <SPAN> tag

```
.maincaptionsmall a {text-decoration: none;}
.maincaptionsmall a:hover {color: yellow;}
```

I see it works well on IE9+ and Chrome 14+. Hopes that help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
.maincaptionsmall a {text-decoration:none;}
.maincaptionsmall a:hover {color: yellow;}
```

Comment: @Amin: I see a line like `a.maincaptionsmall:link {text-decoration:none !important;}` in your slides2.css. That is incorrect. Does the site have your updated CSS (or) are you trying the changes in local?

Comment: @Harry NP. We here to help and you are helping.

Comment: Its done buddy. First i added without !important, so nothing happened, thats why I changed it to !important. :-) now, its not important cuz I got solution ... ;-p

Answer (score 0):

Try the rule

```
.maincaptionsmall a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its coz due to `JS`function, then you can try using inline css within ur JS

```
$(function() 
{
$('.maincaptionsmall').wrapInner('<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://google.com"></a>');
});
```

Comment: inline css in js function also doens't work. best way was css for span tag. anyhow thnx for your post. regards

Comment: @Amin: am doubt have you tried inline css in JS ?? coz heres live demo  and its working cool !! http://jsfiddle.net/hh9dx/1/

Comment: Yes you are right, Actually I have test it, but maybe cuz of my browser cash, I didn't see it, now I checked it again , its working.. thnx buddy :-)

Comment: @Amin: You welcome, well show lil encouragement , but upvote or mark answer, i thnk tushar gupta already answerd  1st